# Solving multi-nominal equation combinatorial way

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

I need to prove in a combintorical way the next equation:

$$\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3=n} \binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3}
=3^n$$

What's the right combinatorical way in which i need to look on this kind of equations? (Any kind of multi-nominal equations)

Comment: This counts all possible ways to divvy up into partitions of exactly three (not necessarily nonempty, or proper as subsets) cells of a set of size $n$. More generally, look up the multinomial expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We count the number of words of length $n$ using the alphabet $\{x,y,z\}$. It is clear that there are $3^n$ such words.

But for any $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that $a_1+a_2+a_3=n$, there are $\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3}$ words with exactly $a_1$ $x$'s, $a_2$ $y$'s, and $a_3$ $z$'s.
For there are by definition $\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3}$ ways to decide **where** the $a_1$ $x$'s, $a_2$ $y$'s, and $a_3$ $z$'s go.

So the number of words is
$$\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3=n} \binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3}.$$
We have counted the same thing in two different ways: the answers must be the same.

If you are algebraically inclined, note the following generalization of the Binomial Theorem.
$$(x+y+z)^3=\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3=n}\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3}x^{a_1}y^{a_2}z^{a_3}.$$
To get your identity, put $x=y=z=1$.

The above formula generalizes readily. In its general form, it is called the Multinomial Theorem**.

If you don't like words, we can count the number of ways to distribute $n$ different presents among $3$ kids.

Comment: intuition-wise: does it work the same with K amount of a's? means i'll get k^n possibilities?

Comment: Yes, the reasonable generalization works. The argument is almost the same.

Comment: It's quite easy once i properly look on the question, Thanks. :-)

Comment: You are welcome. The point of many of these answers is that once one looks at things the right way, they become much easier.

Comment: one more question - Now that i understand the overall picture. How does the sum actually work? i mean, I still can't understand how to properly use the the a1+a2+a3=n under the sum. It represents the different options i have?

Comment: Yes. Let's look at the words concrete example, with $n=10$, and $a_1=2$, $a_2=5$, $a_3=3$ (they needn't be distinct). How many ways are there to **choose** where the $2$ $x$'s, $5$ $y$'s, and $3$ $z$'s go. By the **definition** of $\binom{10}{2,5,3}$, that's how many ways. Let's calculate another way. The location of the $2$ $x$'s can be chosen in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways. For **each** of these ways, the location of the $y$'s can be chosen in $\binom{8}{5}$ ways, and now we only have $1$ way of placing the $z$'s. So the number is $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{5}$. (Continued)

Comment: Now express $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{5}$ in terms of factorials. We get $\frac{10!}{2!8!}\frac{8!}{5!3!}$. This simplifies to $\frac{10!}{2!5!3!}$, the multinomial coefficient. General $n,a_1,a_2,a_3$ works the same way.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you once again.